# Reduce space between icon and text in Polymer's paper-icon-item

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to reduce the space between the icon and text in `paper-icon-item`. How do I do that?

[image]

I tried

```
paper-icon-item {
  --paper-item-icon: {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
```

But its not making any difference.

Comment: check the box model, see if you can remove padding from the text not the icon itself.

Comment: I'm having the opposite issue. The icon is right against the text and I can't seem to create some white space. I've tried increasing the width, increasing the padding/margin using `--paper-item-icon`, etc., but the icon and text are always right next to one another.

Comment: Update: I realized that I forgot the item-icon attribute so the icon area was blank while the iron-icon I was trying to move away was part of the text area. Once I did this it was easy to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the icon area's width, the default is 56px.
Example:

```
paper-icon-item {
    --paper-item-icon-width: 40px;
}
```